# Spring Boot and context path

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-boot

I've done a sample web application recently using spring boot and groovy templates. I didn't find a simple way to provide my templates with servlet context path to get static resources urls right. Is there a way to do it? A more general way than inject request or servletcontext into controller methods? One thing i can think of is custom model attribute, but i think it's a hack rather than good solution to the problem.

Comment: An example would be helpful. Spring Boot applications are typically deployed to the root, but you may be looking for `@{/css/my.css}`.

Comment: I've read about @ function for thymeleaf templates. Here i use groovy templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In groovy templates a RequestContext object is available as a parameter with name 'spring'. So all I had to do in view is

```
spring.getContextUrl('/link/to/some/resource')
```